# Licensing c program

Tags: c, licensing

How would i licence my c command line program, e.g limited functionality without a serial number?

Answer (score 2):

Depends what licensing means ...

Write the license text into the source code resp. show the license text when installing or starting the program.

If you want prevent users from copying the program, things get complicated, you might need some hardware dongle.

Or just make it GPL and give the source code away ...

Answer (score 1):

Include a EULA (End User License Agreement) in your program which users will have to accept while installing/using your application. You can get lots of sample EULAs in Internet. Replace the Names appropriately. But remember, you are gonna do things at your own risk. Read the EULA well, modify it to suit your needs.